# Matrix element-wise exponential

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Does anyone know any mathematical notation for representing the exponential of the elements of a matrix $A$ (taken entry-wise similar to Matlab exp($A$))? Also, if you are aware of any properties that could be used for this case, I would much appreciate that you could refer me to the relevant sources.

Comment: You mean something like this: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}e^1&e^2\\e^3&e^4\end{bmatrix}$$ ??

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: I am not aware of notation for this. It is ambiguous since the matrix exponential $e^A$ is not simply the exponential function applied entry-wise, and this may sometimes be denoted $\exp(A)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is common to write $\exp[A]$ (and more generally, $f[A]$) to refer to the application of an entrywise exponential (or function) to $A$.  This is the notation used, for example, [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.1235).

It is notable that this exponential can be expressed via a power series as
$$
\exp(A) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!} A^{\circ k}
$$
where $A ^{\circ k}$ is a [Hadamard power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)#Analogous_operations), i.e. the entrywise application of $x \mapsto x^k$.  Consequently: if $A$ is positive semidefinite, so is $\exp(A)$.  For a citation on this fact, see Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. May I understand that such expression is also applicable to a rectangular matrix?

Comment: Sure, works just as well with rectangular matrices. Of course, "positive definiteness" doesn't apply in that setting